# How to use the SELECT clause twice in a sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql

**I want to have a table where I can view today's balance as well as yesterday's balance as two different column. Is there any way I can select from two different dates?**

Below is the SQL statement I have tried however I am not able to see the yesterday balance.

`(SELECT food.food_id, food.food_name, food.food_chi_name, food.food_category, food.chinesechar, SUM(inventory.tmr_input+inventory.final_balance), SUM(inventory.balance), SUM(inventory.input), SUM(inventory.reject), SUM(inventory.final_balance), SUM(inventory.tmr_input), SUM(inventory.sale), SUM(inventory.theoritical), SUM(inventory.yest_theoritical), SUM(inventory.3PMsale), SUM(inventory.3PMbalance), SUM(inventory.wholesale) FROM inventory INNER JOIN food ON inventory.food_id=food.food_id WHERE food.outlet = 'T11' AND inventory.date = '04/30/2021' GROUP BY food.food_id ORDER BY food.food_id ASC); (SELECT SUM(inventory.balance) as yesterday_balance FROM inventory INNER JOIN food ON inventory.food_id=food.food_id WHERE food.outlet = 'T11' AND inventory.date = '04/29/2021' GROUP BY food.food_id ORDER BY food.food_id ASC);`

Comment: Describe the problem you want to solve.  Provide sample data and desired results.  Simplify your data if possible to focus on what you don't understand.  Dumping a complex query is not the same as an explanation.

Comment: ***PLEASE*** format your query so that it's not all one line.  Single line queries are almost impossible to read and maintain.  Make use of carriage returns and indentations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subselect  for that purpose

And using aliases helps to get a better overview

```
SELECT 
    f1.food_id
    , f1.food_name
    , f1.food_chi_name
    , f1.food_category
    , f1.chinesechar
    , SUM(i1.tmr_input+i1.final_balance)
    , SUM(i1.balance)
    , SUM(i1.input)
    , SUM(i1.reject)
    ,SUM(i1.final_balance)
    , SUM(i1.tmr_input)
    , SUM(i1.sale)
    , SUM(i1.theoritical)
    , SUM(i1.yest_theoritical)
    , SUM(i1.`3PMsale`)
   , SUM(i1.`3PMbalance`)
    , SUM(i1.wholesale) 
    ,(SELECT SUM(i2.balance)  
    FROM 
    inventory i2 INNER JOIN food f2 ON i2.food_id=f2.food_id 
    WHERE f2.outlet = 'T11' AND i2.date = '04/29/2021' 
    AND  f2.food_id  = f1.food_id
    ) as yesterday_balance
FROM 
    inventory i1
        INNER JOIN 
    food f1 ON i1.food_id=f1.food_id 
WHERE 
    f1.outlet = 'T11' 
    AND i1.date = '04/30/2021' 
GROUP BY f1.food_id 
ORDER BY f1.food_id ASC;
```